# Why isn't overflow:hidden working in IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Please take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UQNJA/1/

It looks fine in all modern browsers and even IE7/8 and 9. But in IE6 the red and pink borders are not containing the `<li>s` which are being floated left. Anyway to make it work?

P.S. I would never support IE6 but my client demands it :(

CSS:

```
@import "http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/reset/reset.css";
body { padding: 20px; }

#topnav { border: 4px solid red; }
#topnav ul { list-style-type: none; overflow: hidden; border: 4px solid pink; }
#topnav ul li { border-right: 1px solid green; float: left; }
#topnav ul li a { text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; padding: 0 20px; background: red; }
#topnav ul li a:hover { background: yellow; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>about</span></a></li>        
        <li><a href=""><span>services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try clearing the floats by adding a clearing last list item: <li class="clear-floats" style="clear: both"><!-- --></li> (empty comment is important for IE6)

Comment: "Why isn't ... working in IE6?" has only one real answer :-)

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa yes already tried that and other manual clear boths, no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support IE6, you must understand [haslayout](http://haslayout.net/).

Add `zoom:1` to `#topnav ul` and to give it haslayout and clear the floats.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE6 to test with, but when styling menus, put all styles on the `A` tag, not the `LI` (other than `float:left` - so move that border to the `A`), make `A` `display:block` and that may fix it.

And as Mikko says, clear your floats:

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>about</span></a></li>        
        <li><a href=""><span>services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The manual clear does bring the red border down. But the ul's pink border still doesn't contains the list items, even if I put a second clear before the closing ul tag.

Comment: no that actually makes the ul stop containing the list items even in ff. Anyway the more important part was getting the red border to contain everything, the ul not containing isn't that important for what I'm trying to do so I will just forget about it.

Comment: You can always put a height value on the UL, or move the border to the surrounding DIV.

Answer (score -1):

I think I've found your problem - your using IE6. If IE6 was an animal it would be taken outside and shot.

Jokes aside: Overflow hidden IS supported by IE6, surprisingly.

Your real problem is your `UL` is not positioned relatively. Try this:

```
ul {position:relative;}
```